# Why is $\frac{CD}{BD}=\frac{AC}{AB}$?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, triangles, circles

[image]

Here, $I$ is the in-center. According to my book,

$$\frac{CD}{BD}=\frac{AC}{AB}\tag{1}$$

My book didn't provide any justification for this claim. How do I prove $(1)$?

Comment: hint: the distance from I to AB and to AC is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\angle BDA=\alpha, \angle BAD=\angle DAC=\beta$. Using the law of sines:
$$\frac{AB}{\sin \alpha}=\frac{BD}{\sin \beta},\frac{AC}{\sin (\pi-\alpha)}=\frac{DC}{\sin \beta}$$

Note that $\sin (\pi-\alpha)=\sin \alpha$ thus we just divide two identities to get the result:

$$\frac{AB}{\sin \alpha}=\frac{BD}{\sin \beta}\tag{1}$$

$$\frac{AC}{\sin \alpha}=\frac{DC}{\sin \beta}\tag{2}$$

$(1)\div(2):$

$$\frac{AB}{AC}=\frac{BD}{DC}$$

$$\frac{CD}{BD}=\frac{AC}{AB}$$

This result is called **Angle bisector theorem**.

Answer (score 2):

It is from bisector, there is a property. You can add the areas too.

$$\frac{CD}{BD}=\frac{AC}{AB}=\frac{\triangle ADC}{\triangle ABD}$$

Answer (score 1):

The result is a consequence of the Angle Bisector Theorem.

It can be proved in many ways - I detail a short proof using the areas.

We consider the ratio of the areas of the two triangles  $ \triangle ABD$ and $\triangle ACD$, which are created by the angle bisector in $A$.

We compute the areas using two different formulas.

Let $h$ denote the height of the triangles on base $BC$.

Then we find that
$$
{| \Delta ABD | \over | \Delta ACD |} = {{1 \over 2} BD \ h \over
{1 \over 2} CD \ h} = {BD \over CD} \tag{1}
$$

Let $\alpha$ be half of the angle in $A$. Then we also find that
$$
{| \Delta ABD | \over | \Delta ACD |} = {{1 \over 2} AB \ AD \ \sin \alpha \over
{1 \over 2} AC \ AD \ \sin \alpha} = {AB \over AC} \tag{2}
$$

Equating (1) and (2), we get
$$
{AB \over AC} = {BD \over CD}
$$

Equivalently, we can write as
$$
{AC \over AB} = {CD \over BD} 
$$

[image]